# Button Panel on the custom View in android

Tags: android, android-layout, view, controls

I want to create a button panel that provides game options to the player. This panel has to slide in and out of the canvas as shown in the figure below.

[image]

What approaches can I take to implement this. Can I use normal buttons?
 Any examples would be appreciated.

Thanks
Pat

Comment: Look into the `FrameLayout`ViewGroup.

Comment: I sorry can u give me an example. What I want is a sliding panel. As I know framelayout can contain the game view not the sliding button panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all yes you can use normal button for your slide in & out panel. Now, how to do it?

First of all create a separate layout xml file for you panel e.g. "**panel.xml**".

Now use the **include** tag in your game xml file and set it's **gravity : TOP** and **visibility : GONE** and set it's id to panel i.e.

```
android:id="@+id/panel";
```

Now create a folder named "**anim**" inside your projects **res** folder. Here create two xml files slide_in.xml & slide_out.xml these xml flies will help you in getting the slide in & out effect. Code for these xml file is as follow

slide_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fromYDelta="-100%p" 
     android:toYDelta="0%p"
     android:duration="3000"/>
```

slide_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fromYDelta="0%p" 
     android:toYDelta="-100%p"
     android:duration="3000"/>
```

Now all the things required to build your slide in & out panel are ready.

IMPLEMENTATION:

NOTE: maintain a boolean variable **isPanelVisible** to keep check of visibility state of the panel.

Create two Animation class object **slideIn** & **slideOut** and one View class object **panel** for the panel.xml which we included in the game xml file, then initialize them like this:

```
Animation slideIn= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.slide_in);
Animation slideOut= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.slide_out);
View panel = findViewById(R.id.panel);
```

Now when the user clicks on the button to show the slide in & out panel inside the onClickListener() method do something like this:

```
if(isPanelVisible){
    isPanelVisible = false;
    panel.startAnimation(slideOut);
    panel.setVisibility(View.Gone);
} else{
    isPanelVisible = true;
    panel.startAnimation(slideIn);
    panel.setVisibility(View.Visible);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please see my answer. I was not able to make it work.

Comment: Yes, when I executed the code under button nothing happened in the UI. UI code is given above. No errors, its just button panel did not appear. If I make it visible, it doesn't disappear on button click. Button click is getting executed I checked that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for your response. I was able to do it on a normal Layout (eg. relative layout). But in the frame layout the button panel did not appear. Here is my xml. gameView is a java class extending View. gameoption_panel is a linear layout with some buttons. I have added a button just to execute the isPanelVisible code section.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.gameView
        android:id="@+id/puzzleView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <include layout="@layout/gameoption_panel"
        android:id="@+id/panel"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

 <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string"
            android:textColor="#FFFFAA" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.gameView
        android:id="@+id/puzzleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/panel"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/gameoption_panel"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string"
        android:textColor="#FFFFAA" />
</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I ll try in few hours and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Then who has scored my answer? I thought it was you.

Comment: its not me, I dont have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: I tried out that layout, its shows the same limitation.  First it complains that 'relative or FrameLayout parent is useless'. I tried just with the relative layout but no luck. If I make the button panel visible at design time it stays visible, but runtime nothing happens. I commented out all animations as well. any suggestions?

Comment: See FrameLayout is like a stack the first Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top. So the last view declared inside the layout has the highest preference. Try to control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.

Comment: nope nothing seems to work at runtime. I changed the order of the panels and used android:layout_gravity attributes as well. No luck. Whatever I do at runtime to the panel doesnt have any impact. Even if I change the background color of the panel, that doesnt apply

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Its working now, had to do a lot of debugging to figure out the issue. It was bug in my implementation.
Btw, the animation slides the panel from top to bottom. I just need it slide in from the top just to the button height. Then slid out when close button in the panel is pressed.